# Пустой параметр запроса логического поля ms access

Tags: sql, база-данных, ms-access

Как вывести все записи логического поля? *Ложь*, *Истина* выводит по отдельности. А что  нужно передать, чтобы получить все записи?
Код запроса:
`((Protokol.IsPlan)=IIf([Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]=1,(Protokol.IsPlan) Like "",IIf([Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]=2,0,IIf([Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]=3,-1))))`

Comment: Покажите, в какой текст конвертируется ЭТО после подстановки. А для начала - трансформируйте `WHERE field=value` в `WHERE field IN (value)`, и для варианта "все" передавайте в качестве value значение `true,false`.

Comment: В условии отбора ставлю так     `IIf([Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]=2;0;IIf([Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]=3;-1;([Protokol].[IsPlan] In (Истина;Ложь))))` и все равно выдает только true либо false когда выбран 3 вариант

Comment: Повторяю. **Покажите, в какой текст конвертируется ЭТО после подстановки.** То есть никаких `[Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]` в тексте быть не должно, должны быть уже подставленные значения.

Comment: Ни в какой не конвертируется, значения берутся из группы переключателей в форме. Или я вас неправильно понял.

Comment: Так в том и вопрос - какие именно значения подставляются в текст запроса вместо `[Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]`?

Comment: То значение которое выбрано в данный момент: 1 или 2 или 3

Comment: Ну будет что-то вроде `WHERE ([Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]=3) OR (Protokol.IsPlan=([Forms]![Отчет]![Группа100]=1))`